# Bootstrap Methods - Mathematical Rigour

Tags: bootstrap

I'm looking for sources that present an Introduction to Bootstrap Methods in a mathematically rigorous way.

I have looked at books such as "An Introduction to the Bootstrap - Efron" and "Bootstrap methods and their applications" but these have not presented the material in a mathematically rigorous way and seem to focus more on the Heuristics.

Comment: Wasseman's "All of Statistics" talks about the bootstrap in terms of convergence in distribution of the empirical CDF of a sample to that of the population.

Comment: I'm mainly interested in the accuracy of bootstrap estimate from a theoretical point of view e.g. is the bootstrap estimate itself biased (I have read that is is nearly unbiased - is there an expression for its bias), what is it's variance etc.